# More on the primes and sequences of the form $a^n+b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I have two questions which hopefully are not trivial, although they could be:

> 1) Is it true that for every natural number $M$ there exist pair of natural numbers $(a,b)$ such that the sequence $a^n+b$ contains exactly $M$ primes?
>
> 2) Is it true that for every natural number $M$ there exist infinitely many pairs of natural numbers $(a_1,b_1),(a_2,b_2),...(a_k,b_k),...$ such that the sequences $s_k(n)=a_k^n+b_k; k=1,2,...$ contain exactly $M$ primes?

Comment: These are likely to be very difficult questions.  Note that numbers of the form $2^n + 1$ are composite when $n$ has an odd prime factor, is known to be prime when $n = 1,2,4,8,16$, and otherwise is [known to be composite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number#Primality_of_Fermat_numbers) for $n = 2^k$ with $5 \le k \le 32$.  It is unknown if there are any other primes of this form.

Comment: One of four questions OP has posted to m.se on $a^n+b$. See OP's user page. This one has also been posted to MO as http://mathoverflow.net/questions/223025/on-the-primes-and-sequences-of-the-form-anb